# Decimals Stumping Program

Tags: python, decimal

```
Battery_Initial = raw_input("Enter Current Capacity:"))

if Battery_Initial < 0:
    print 'Battery Reading Malfunction'

elif Battery_Initial > 80:
    print 'Battery Reading Malfunction'
```

This is my program so far. I was wondering if there is a way to only allow inputs such as 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, basically on a 0.5 interval.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `float()` instead of `int()`, as `int()` expects decimal input not floats.

```
Battery_Initial = float(raw_input("Enter Current Capacity:"))
```

**output:**

```
$ python so27.py
Enter Current Capacity:0.5

$ python so27.py
Enter Current Capacity:81.1
Battery Reading Malfunction

$ python so27.py
Enter Current Capacity:-1.2
Battery Reading Malfunction

$ python so27.py
Enter Current Capacity:-1
Battery Reading Malfunction
```

use something like this:

```
In [271]: [i/float(2) for i in range(1,10)]
Out[271]: [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5]
```

**usage:**

```
if  Battery_Initial in (i/float(2) for i in range(1,10)):
        #do something here
```

or as suggested by @Joran Beasley :

```
if  Battery_Initial % 0.5 ==0:
    #do something here
```

Comment: Thanks but also I was wondering how to only allow inputs of a 0.5 interval.

Comment: For example 0.5 , 1.0 , 1.5, but not allow 1.7

Comment: Sorry I am confused what "print 1.5%0.5 == 0" means and where am I placing this in my function?

Comment: @MichaelAlexanderRiechmann see the updated solution, you need to use `if` condition.

Comment: elif  Battery_Initial % 0.5 ==0:
    print 'Battery Only Charges Increments of 0.5'

I added this to my program but it still allows inputs of 1.7 and such.

Comment: Note that doing `==` on floats is dangerous, as small rounding errors might lead to weird results.

Comment: `elif float(Battery_Initial) % 0.5 !=0: #bad not a multiple of 0.5`

Comment: What does the ! mean though?